# Is there a way to find (potentially) multiple results with re.search?

Tags: python, regex

While parsing file names of TV shows, I would like to extract information about them to use for renaming. I have a working model, but it currently uses 28 if/elif statements for every iteration of filename I've seen over the last few years. I'd love to be able to condense this to something that I'm not ashamed of, so any help would be appreciated.

Phase one of this code repentance is to hopefully grab multiple episode numbers.  I've gotten as far as the code below, but in the first entry it only displays the first episode number and not all three.

```
import re

def main():
    pattern = '(.*)\.S(\d+)[E(\d+)]+'
    strings = ['blah.s01e01e02e03', 'foo.s09e09', 'bar.s05e05']

    #print(strings)
    for string in strings:
        print(string)
        result = re.search("(.*)\.S(\d+)[E(\d+)]+", string, re.IGNORECASE)
        print(result.group(2))

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

This outputs:

```
blah.s01e01e02e03
01
foo.s09e09
09
bar.s05e05
05
```

It's probably trivial, but regular expressions might as well be Cuneiform most days. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can use `findall` to find all `e\d+`, but it cannot find overlapping matches, which makes it impossible to use `s\d+` together with it (i.e. you can't distinguish `e02` in `"foo.s01e006e007`" from that of `"age007.s01e001"`), and Python doesn't let you use variable-length lookbehind (to make sure `s\d+` is before it without overlapping).

The way to do this is to find `\.s\d+((?:e\d+)+)$` then split the resultant group 1 in another step (whether by using `findall` with `e\d+`, or by splitting with `(?<!^)(?=e)`).

```
text = 'blah.s01e01e02e03'
match = re.search(r'\.(s\d+)((?:e\d+)+)$', text, re.I)
season = match.group(1)
episodes = re.findall(r'e\d+', match.group(2), re.I)
print(season, episodes)
# => s01 ['e01', 'e02', 'e03']
```

Comment: yeah, my bad. I posted that and then reread the question.  Originally thought it was to not loop.  Meant to edit the answer and then I had to leave all of a sudden x.x

Comment: This will work wonders, thanks!  And thanks for explaining the regex in detail.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` instead of `re.search` will return a list of all matches

Answer (score 1):

If you can make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you could make use of repeating capture groups in the pattern, and then use `.captures()`

For example:

```
import regex

s = "blah.s01e01e02e03"
pattern = r"\.(s\d+)(e\d+)+"
m = regex.search(pattern, s, regex.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m.captures(1)[0], m.captures(2))
```

Output:

```
s01 ['e01', 'e02', 'e03']
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TYs/C8IwFMT3fIpHpoSW0D@b4CBSxEVBR@sQ69MGTBpeIuinjw108Dhu@N2d/8Zxcm1KxvqJIhA@8cNYgDXw20uPKlQ1ZjdYtZx5HSOSm1vivRKhvxdSYM6CM5tx/quAmoZRLOsSQrkU@93heOq2m3MnmXmAXTGY5cm4KKwatI9vwiBqeamuJfyRRsqUfg) and a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/43IkgD/1).

---

Or using `.capturesdict ()` with named capture groups.

For example:

```
import regex

s = "blah.s01e01e02e03"
pattern = r"\.(?P<season>s\d+)(?P<episodes>e\d+)+"
m = regex.search(pattern, s, regex.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m.capturesdict())
```

Output:

```
{'season': ['s01'], 'episodes': ['e01', 'e02', 'e03']}
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LYw9C8IwGIT3/IqQKaElVLuJVkSKuKjo2iW2b23AfJA3gv762ECPW@7u4fwvTs7WKWnjXYg0wAu@hCDdUfZ8q0litYLsNVQ1I17FCMHOa2Cd5PvbFkGhsw12QyFyBq/RDYAN5KZgxGQ4v8oZDf3El4@SYrkM59Plem@Ph0criB6p2RA6ywdtIzeyVz5@AuCg@8iFSOkP).

---

**Note** that the notation `[E(\d+)]` that you used is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that matches 1 or the listed characters like `E` `(` a digit `+` `)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up.  While I don't think I'll go this route immediately, I'm going to try it out so I can add it to my tool set.